# How to disable web/log directory browsing in HDFS web ui

Tags: hadoop, nosql, ambari

I want to disable log directory browsing in the HDFS web ui. You can see the browsable log content in the below image. Please advice on how to block these file access through the ui.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not supported but you can setup Kerberos to secure this web UI (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-3801)